# Looking for an early 60s timeframe young adult sci fi book?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

I am looking for a book I read as a young boy.  I thought it was "Journey to Jupiter" but having looked at a book by this name in Wiki the synopsis is not the same.  I do not think there are two books with this same title but for decades I have remembered the book at Journey to Jupiter.....
The book I read took place on Jupiter and is about a family of a scientific colony trying to establish life on the Jovian giant.  The book ends with the young boy in the story finding a small green plant emerging from Jupiter's soil.

If anyone can help identify this I would be grateful.  I do not recall any more details.

Comment: Could it possible be *Farmer in the Sky*, which involves farming on Ganymede, Jupiter's moon?

Comment: I have a hard time imagining a science fiction work in the 60s making the mistake of thinking that there is a surface on Jupiter itself.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You'd be surprised how many stories assume a surface on Jupiter if you descend deep enough. [Here's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Unintentional) by Asimov. Hm, that one's 1942 though.

Comment: FuzzyBoots, Todd Wilcox and Mr. Lister, thank you all for your thoughtful contributions.  It was not Farmer in the Sky, and I am sure the author knew what the surface of Jupiter was but opted for a story that would work with young children.  It was clearly on a surface on Jupiter and the family in the story was striving to create the colony and the villain was trying to sabotage the effort by destroying or poisoning plants put in by the colonists.

Comment: As it happens, there ***ARE*** two books with that same title, and I believe Lee Eckhardt has identified the one you're looking for. It might have helped just a little bit if you had bothered to ***identify*** the book of the same title which you had ruled out, either by naming the author or linking to the "Wiki" synopsis. I'm guessing the wrong *Journey to Jupiter* was [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_Jupiter) by Hugh Walters, am I right?

Comment: By the way, you can easily get a list of sci-fi books with that title by doing a [title search in the Internet Speculative Fiction Database](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=journey+to+jupiter&type=Fiction+Titles).

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, I guess I should have put my answer here. I am pretty sure it is [*Journey to Jupiter: A Dig Allen Space Explorer Adventure*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?416431) by [Joseph Greene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Greene_(writer)). Part of [a series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?17891).

Comment: Sounds mighty likely! http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10343603-journey-to-jupiter

Answer (score 5):

Kind of stretching it here, but could you be conflating two Lester Del Rey young adult novels of the era?  [Outpost of Jupiter](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25462) takes place in the Jovian system, and [Moon of Mutiny](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25437) has a sub-plot involving finding plants growing on the Moon.  The writing style is very similar and I could imagine conflating them if you had read a lot of these books in a short time, long ago.

I just loved the cover of Moon of Mutiny when I ran across it in my elementary school library, back in the Space Age.

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure this is 'Journey to Jupiter: A Dig Allen Space Explorer Adventure'